# Cannot connect to Sql server on Godaddy using the plesk delux hosting

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, plesk

I am using the Plesk hosting for my asp.net mvc 4 website with Sql Server 2012.

My Connection string is the following:

```
metadata=res://*/Models.FolioData.csdl|res://*/Models.FolioData.ssdl|res://*/Models.FolioData.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="Data Source=184.168.47.13;Initial Catalog=MyDataBase;Integrated Security=True;User ID=*****;Password=*******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework"
```

But i keep getting the error:

```
 Error.

An error occurred while processing your request.
```

**Database server dashboard:**

[image]

Comment: Could you share screenshot of plesk "Tools & Settings" > "Database Servers" - there should be how SQL server registered in PLesk.

Comment: @vini Please make sure you use correct details. Or if you unsure, please kindly contact your hosting provider.

Comment: Hi we also getting same issue while connecting to the database to the application using My SQL server from Plesk Panel. Can any one help to to conquer this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ability to connect to SQL server depends on:

- instance name like MSSQLSERVER or SQLEXPRESS
- listening IPs and ports

For example, instance name of your SQL server is SQLEXPRESS and it listening on 127.0.0.1:1433

So your connection string will be Data Source=127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS;

If instance name is MSSQLSERVER it can be omitted: Data Source=127.0.0.1;

SQL server configurations management you should have "Active=Yes" and "Enabled=Yes" for necessary IP address:

[image: SQL-server-configurations-management-network]

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a long time ago, but I'm having the same problems this week.  In my case, the problem was actual intermittent MySQL Server connectivity issues.  These are known by the Go Daddy hosting team and supposedly will be resolved ASAP.  I've had connectivity problems on and off for the last two weeks.